# how can i get one value from one field (Crystal report)

Tags: crystal-reports, report

I get one field `V_Name` from Database is`"Name,StartTime:13:56,EndTime:16:56"`, how can i just get only one value `13:56` from it? i only want the start time under the column start time. i've tried `choose(1,table.field)` but it seems only take the first index Name, and the return type should be string. please suggest.
 Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
// {@end_time}

// create array from comma-delimited list
Stringvar Array values := Split( "Name,StartTime:13:56,EndTime:16:56", ",");

// extract "16:56"; convert to time
Time( Split( values[3], ":")[2] + ":" + Split( values[3], ":")[3] );
```

Comment: Hi Craig, thank you very much. this function works. but i've got another problem when using array, it always indicate the subscript ,ust between 1 and the size of the array. I've tried:                         if Ubound(values)>=3 then Time( Split( values[3], ":")[2] + ":" + Split( values[3], ":")[3] ); but it's not working. please suggest. thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

If the format of the string is always the same you can get the value between character 16 and 21. Create a formula "StartTime" and place this code there:

```
Mid ("Name,StartTime:13:56,EndTime:16:56",16 ,5 )
```

This should return 13:56

To make it a real formula replace `"Name,StartTime:13:56,EndTime:16:56"` with your field, it will be something like `{table.V_Name}`.